# GitLab pipeline run PowerShell cannot run Nuget

Tags: powershell, gitlab, nuget, pipeline, gitlab-ci-runner

I had installed NuGet Package into my server

[image]

But as I run the GitLab pipeline, it return error saying that there is no NuGet command

[image]

Below is the PowerShell script that I ran and hit error:

[image]

Had been trying to install and uninstall NuGet and setup the environment variable. Restarted machine few time, tested in the machine that NuGet is successfully installed. But when run the pipeline, PowerShell cannot read NuGet command.

What I want to achieve is to allow my pipeline to read NuGet command from the PowerShell.

Comment: First, did you run your PS1 script locally and it works fine? And second, i would try the absolute path instead just "nuget" to test. like $nugetPath = "C:\Path\To\nuget.exe"  # Replace with the actual path to nuget.exe

Comment: Algo, try to pass the command as a String, like this: Invoke-Expression -Command "nuget help"